# Do refunded managed items need to be consumed?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

In my app I provide a Premium upgrade through a *managed* purchase (it can only be bought once) - not a subscription.

When a purchase is re-funded, the user doesn't seem to be able to re-purchase the upgrade:

`int billingFlowResponseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);` returns `ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930792/cant-re-buy-in-app-billing-item-on-google-play-after-it-was-refunded) here seems to suggest that after about 24 hours the user should be able to purchase the item. However more than 36 hours have passed and no luck.

My question is: For a managed item that was refunded or cancelled, do I need to **consume** it in order to be able to purchase it again?

Or do I need to wait for more time..?

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer in the linked question? Deleting cache and all.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Yes (even restart of the device).

Comment: Google just manages payment of managed purchase. Your app is responsible for consuming the product. If you want the user to repurchase the managed product you need to call consume() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have found the way...

What needs to be done is:

1. The client queries the user's purchases (I use the app-billing library).
2. The client contacts the server with the purchase tokens in order to find out which purchases are still valid.
3. The server calls the `GET purchase` endpoint of the Google's API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get), checks if the purchase needs to *consumed* and returns this information to the client. (A purchase needs to be consumed if `purchase.purchaseState == 1 && purchase.consumptionState == 0`).
4. For those purchases that need to be consumed, the client calls `BillingClient::consume()`.

---

It would have been much easier if there was an option in the Play Console to mark items as "consumable" or not - so that there wouldn't be a need to manually consume items if they were "non-consumable" in the first place.